# Updating commit message after git push

Tags: git

I need to edit commit message. There are already a few more commits on top of it. Is there a way just edit a particular commit message?

Tried to rebase and reword the commit message. But it won't allows me to push.

Complaining -

remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected

Answer (score 1):

You can't *safely* do what you are trying to do.

I'll explain how you can push your changes, but if you do everyone else using that repo will have to take additional steps to recover.  (See the `git rebase` documentation for further explanation; generally you shouldn't rebase commits that have been pushed to a remote.)

So first, why is that?

It has to do with how git stores and addresses content, and detects changes.  Every commit has a unique ID which is a SHA1 hash of the commit.  Say you start with this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D <--(master)(origin/master)
```

If you change the commit message on `B`, the calculated hash must change - so as far as git is concerned, you have a new commit (say `B'`) very similar to the old one.

```
A --- B --- C --- D <--(master)(origin/master)
 \
  B'
```

Well, the data for `C` includes its parent hash (which is `B`, not `B'`), so to have a commit whose parent is `B'` means you have to replace `C` with a new commit `C'`.  And this will continue all the way to HEAD.

```
A --- B --- C --- D <--(origin/master)
 \
  B' --- C' --- D' <--(master)
```

Now git doesn't by default want to let you move `origin/master` form `D` to `D'` because it will mess up assumptions made in any other repos that have cloned from `origin`.

You can force it to let you push your change anyway by saying

```
git push -f
```

but if you do:

1) You will need to double check afterwards that nobody else committed anything after `D` to master.  If they did you'll have to rebase those changes onto `D'`

2) Everyone else will have to take extra steps to resync their branches with `origin`, and will have to rebase any local changes they had planned to push to `master` as well.  (If they instead force their push, then they'll move the remote ref back to the old line - restoring the original commit message at `B` - and you'll be in a broken state.  You and anyone who correctly switched to `D'` will potentially lose changes.  This can go back and forth quite messily if allowed to do so; so you need to make sure the entire team is on board with the *correct* way to recover from the upstream rebase.)

If it's worth all that to change the message, that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you push a commit to a remote repository, it's a bad idea to ever edit or delete that commit, as it will mess up anyone who's pulled from that remote before. If you insist on doing this anyway, `git push -f` will override this check (unless the remote repository is set up to disallow this).